# Rasa sdk custom logging

Tags: python, sdk, rasa

Custom logging does not seem to work while using rasa sdk action.
The logger object created does not log to the log file mentioned in the basicConfig params.
Also the logging message format seem to be as per the sdk logs.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend asking this kind of question on the rasa forum (https://forum.rasa.com/); Or if you think you have found a bug, open a github issue for it on https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa-sdk